# css triangle with one responsive side

Tags: css

I've searching for a while, but didn't find a solution.

The problem is that I need css triangle with fixed height (50px) to be stretched on 100% width of the div.

Surely, it can be done via js or jquery, or by replacing with svg, but is there any pure css solution for this?

Comment: Which div? Is triangle inside this div or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure CSS triangle is manageable via borders, and borders doesn't support thickness in percents. So I guess it's impossible.